# Maximum and minimum value of 2nd degree, 2 variable polynomial

Tags: inequality

> Given $x^2+2y^2=1$, where $x$ and $y$ are both real, find the maximum and minimum value of $$6x+11y^2$$

My only method for these kinds of questions are the arithmetic-geometric inequalities and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Because we don't have $xy$ terms, the former won't work. An example of the latter method would be $$(x^2+2y^2)(6^2+(\frac{11y}{2})^2)>=(6x+11y^2)^2$$Closer, but still not there. What other method can I use?

Comment: From $x^2 + 2y^2 = 1$, you can get $y^2$ in terms of $x^2$ that you can then substitute into your expression to determine the limits of.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Good point.

Comment: Re the comment of @JohnOmielan, with respect to the *goals* of finding the min and max, distinguishing between $y > 0$ and $y < 0$ is not relevant, while distinguishing between $x < 0$ and $x > 0$ is relevant.  Therefore, I suggest splitting your work into two cases, depending on whether $x \geq 0,$ or $x < 0$.  Then, within each case, determine the max and min values.  Then, consolidate the analysis of both cases into one final answer.

Answer (score 1):

First express $y^2$ in terms of $x^2$ and then complete the square.

$$11 y^2 +6 x = 11 \cdot \frac{1-x^2}{2} + 6 x$$

$$ = \frac{11}{2} \left(\frac{157}{121} - \left(x - \frac 6{11}\right)^2 \right)$$

Maximum occurs when $~x = \frac{6}{11}$

Minimum occurs when $~\left|x - \frac{6}{11}\right|$  is maximized and given $x \in (-1, 1)$, that occurs when $x = -1$

Answer (score 0):

While I'm unsure what the best general method would be to approach this class of problem, here's how I'd tackle this specific one.

Thinking geometrically, we know x and y must lie on the oval defined by Eq#1.

Looking at each term of the expression, we see $6x$ is minimized at the minimal value of $x$, and $11y^2$ is minimized at $y=0$. As we know x and y to lie on the above oval, we know $x$ quite conveniently achieves its minimum ($x=-1$) when $y=0$; plugging this in we see the expression's minimum is -6.

Conversely, each term is individually maximized at the maximal value of x and y. This is trickier as we can't simultaneously take the maximal value of each on the oval; there must be trade-off between the two variables according to their marginal contributions, so we turn to calculus.

Rearranging terms and substituting, we see:
$$x^2+2y^2=1 \implies y^2=(1-x^2)/2$$
$$6x+11y^2=6x+(11/2)(1-x^2)$$
Knowing the maximum must occur at a stationary point, we derivate the expression and set it equal to zero:
$$6-11x=0\implies x=6/11$$
$$(6/11)^2+2y^2=1 \implies y=\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{85/121}$$
Plugging back into the expression, we get a maximal value of approximately 5.2
$$6\left(\frac{6}{11}\right)+11\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{85}{121}}\right)^2=\frac{229}{44}=5.20\overline4\overline5$$

Hope that helps!